# Get full path of a file/folder located not in the project path

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to get the fullpath of a file/folder that is located in location

> D://Sachin//Reports//excel.xls

but when I call `Path.getfullpath("excel.xls")` it returns me the location

> C:\users\Projname\bin\debug\etc.

What I need is the path other than what it locates in the project because this path i need to give in my data source connection string.

Comment: Do you know what is meant by 'working directory'? It's important to path resolution.

Comment: Usually, to avoid coding fixed paths in the application code, the connection strings are stored in the config file of your application. These strings are complete with the full information to retrieve the associated files or database. So they could be easily modified without changing the program. Why do you need to build the full path to create the connection strings?

Comment: if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension("D:\\UI_excel.xls").Equals(".xls")) { strConnection = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\\UI_excel.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"; }       what i need is "D:\\UI_excel.xls" instead of this i should make a search for this file in entire system not in the current working directory and get its full path and give it in the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

You would have search all files on the system until you found 'excel.xls'. This would take a very long time, and would not even guarantee that you find the correct 'excel.xls'. Do not do this.

I would recommend one of the following solutions instead:

1. Use a constant full path. For example, the file must be located at 'C:\excel.xls'.
2. Use a constant relative path. For example, the file must be in the same directory as the executable.
3. Store the path in some kind of configuration file, such as the registry.
4. Obtain the path from the user, such as with an `OpenFileDialog`.